# Leica Cyclone 5.1 TLS Data referencing using Trimble DGPS

Tags: coordinate-system, lidar, cyclone

I am using a Leica HDS3000 Terrestrial Laser Scanner (TLS) and Cyclone version 5.1 to acquire and process point clouds. Within the manual for Cyclone 5.1, Leica mentions that a user can enter the height of the TLS unit, the X, Y, and Z of a given point below the TLS unit.

Using a Tremble GeoXH, I can post process my location accuracy to 10 cm which is fine for my application. Given that I can get the X, Y, and Z from the Tremble for each station location; how can I project the TLS point cloud into a coordinate system such as WGS 84? It's not clear to me how this is possible within the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that you just collect the point clouds and tie them together. Once you have them tied together you provide known points (i.e. GPS points) and that rectifies the data into a coordinate system.